# Visualisation of logistic regression

Tags: r, ggplot2, logistic-regression

I have a basic and hopefully quick question (gotta start somewhere). Could you good people help me clarify things? :)

When fitting logistic regression model how does the following visualisation:

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point(position=position_jitter(width=0, height=0.1)) + 
  labs(y = 'P(y)') +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,0.5,1))
  geom_smooth(method=glm, method.args=list(family=binomial)) + 
  aes(color = z)
```

... relate to this formula:

```
log_model <- glm(y ~ x * z, df, family=binomial)
```

?

Is this the basis of how the regression lines are drawn on the plot or not quite?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The default formula for `geom_smooth()` is `y ~ x`, but you can change it manually:

```
geom_smooth(method=glm,formula = y ~ x * z, method.args=list(family=binomial))
```

So in the default case that you put out, the line is corresponds to the model

```
glm(y ~ x * z, df, family=binomial)
```